# Save counter value from listView

Tags: flutter

I have a list where I keep the product list object

```
List<ProductList> listProcuct = new List<ProductList>();
```

The model of Object list is

```
 class ProductList{
  String codigo;
  String nombre;
  String marca;
  String tipo;
  String contenido;
  String imagen;
  int count;

  ProductList({
    this.codigo,
    this.nombre,
    this.marca,
    this.tipo,
    this.contenido,
    this.imagen,
    this.count,
  });
}
```

with this object I create a list view, using the list "listProcuct" to map

```
                                        ListView(
                                          children:listProcuct.map((productos) {
                                            return ListTile(
                                              title:Text('${productos.nombre}'),
                                              trailing: new Row(
                                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                                children: <Widget>[
                                                  productos.count != 0 ? 
                                                  new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.remove),
                                                          onPressed: () =>setState(() =>productos.count -= 1),)
                                                      : new Container(),
                                                  new Text(productos.count.toString()),
                                                  new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.add),
                                                    onPressed: () =>setState(() =>productos.count += 1),),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          }).toList(),
                                        ),
```

visually it looks like this
[ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNYHO.jpg)

The problem is that I need to save the counter values ​​of each product object

> productos.count -= 1 or productos.count += 1

I have investigated but I don't know how to save these decrement and increment values of object ProductList in the list:

```
List<ProductList> listProcuct = new List<ProductList>();
```

I need help :(

Comment: Can you make it more clear, because changed value(increment/decrement) is already reflected in the list.

Comment: @Nidheesh I need to update the increment and decrement values ​​of each object stored in the list, because the set state only updates the data in the view and doesn't save it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ListView` Use `ListView.builder` then you will get the position of item and you can update the corresponding item in the list

```
   ListView.builder(
      itemCount: listProcuct.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
        ProductList productos = listProcuct.elementAt(position);
        return ListTile(
          title: Text('${productos.nombre}'),
          trailing: new Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              productos.count != 0
                  ? new IconButton(
                      icon: new Icon(Icons.remove),
                      onPressed: () {
                        productos.count -= 1;
                        updateCount(productos, position);
                      },
                    )
                  : new Container(),
              new Text(productos.count.toString()),
              new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.add),
                onPressed: () {
                  productos.count += 1;
                  updateCount(productos, position);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

and use a function to update the count

```
 void updateCount(ProductList product, int position) {
    setState(() => listProcuct[position] = product);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the right things to increment/decrement:

```
onPressed: () =>setState(() =>productos.count -= 1)
```

so `productos.count` will hold the updated value?? No... because `setState` will also retrigger your query to database and will refresh the value of `productos.count` to its origin value... then, you lose your updated values.

**The solution:**
instead of saving the value to `productos.count`, you will have to save to a new local data structure... try it with just a local variable `int _count` to see how it works... but most likely, you will need to create a `List` with the same length as your query result.

something like this as a variable in your class:

```
List<int> countList=[];
```

then, update the length once you retrieve your query. Then:

```
onPressed: () =>setState(() =>countList[index] -= 1)
```

Comment: I had also tried that way, but at the time of ordering the data with the object it became more difficult, luckily I could solve it, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using stateful widgets the mutable State should be stored inside the state class outside of the build method.
Why? because the stateful and stateless widgets are inmutable so, you can't store mutable data there.
But the stateful widgets achive this `mutability` by having a state that is maintained from one frame to another.
But the build method is called in every frame so you should not either create your state there,and also the build function should not have any side effects so just store the list as an attribute of the state class as shown below:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<ProductList> listProduct = [
    ProductList(count: 2),
    ProductList(count: 3),
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(children: [
          for (var productos in listProduct)
            ListTile(
              title: Text('${productos.nombre}'),
              trailing: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  if (productos.count != 0)
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            productos.decrementCounter() ;
                          });
                        }),
                  Text(productos.count.toString()),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                    onPressed: () => setState(() => productos.count += 1),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Notice how I did not used the `new` keyword as is optional and only clutters more the code, and used collection if and collection for, for displaying each listTile and with the collection if you don't have to show an empty container if the condition is not met.

Comment: ohh I had not taken into account the frames .. thank you